# C#: How to solve System.FormatException on WCF Service which use X509 Certificate for Authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, x509

I'm facing that problem which I'm struggling to understand. What I try to do is creating WCF Service. On this service I try to use certificate on server and client side for authentication. Here is my code and the exception list.

> System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or
>   string.    at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr,
>   Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)    at
>   System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
>   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadIdentity(IdentityElement
>   element)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase
>   host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement,
>   Action`1 addBaseAddress, Boolean skipHost)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(ConfigLoader
>   configLoader, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement
>   serviceSection)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ApplyConfiguration()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.ApplyConfiguration()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection
>   baseAddresses)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type
>   serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[]
>   baseAddresses)    at
>   Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.CreateServiceHost(Type type,
>   ServiceKind kind)    at
>   Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.OpenService(ServiceInfo
>   info)

```
namespace Test
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]

    class TestService:ITestUser
    {
        public string Print(string text)
        {
            return "You've printed: " + text;
        }
    }
}

namespace Test
{
    [DataContract]
    public class TestUser 
    {
        [DataMember]
        string Username;
        [DataMember]
        string Password;
    }
}

namespace Test
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITestUser
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Print(string text);
        [OperationContract]
        bool Authorise(string Username, string Password);
    }
}
```

App.Config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service 
        behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehaviour" 
        name="Test.TestService">
        <endpoint 
          address="" 
          binding="wsHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding"
          contract="Test.ITestUser"
          name="TestSecureEndPoint" 
          isSystemEndpoint="true">
          <identity>
            <certificate encodedValue="TestCertificate" />
            <certificateReference isChainIncluded="true" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/TestService/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureBinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CustomBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication
                certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust"
                revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate
              findValue="TestCertificate"
              x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
              storeLocation="LocalMachine"
              storeName="TrustedPublisher"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Putting together the words "Base64 encoded" and "encodedValue" in your config, one can surmise that you're using the wrong value. It's supposed to be the base64-encoded representation of your certificate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199525/wcf-obtaining-certificate-encoded-value